# Elasticfox For Firefox4 Mac

Tags: amazon-ec2

I recently upgraded Firefox to version 4 on my Mac and now it seems Elasticfox no longer works.  Does anyone know if and when Elasticfox will get updates for FF4 compatibility?

Also, are any of you using an alternative to Elasticfox in order to manage your instances?  Right now I am using the AWS console, but I manage 14 EC2 instances for 5 different clients and constantly having to log in & out between them is a pain.  That is why I prefer something like Elasticfox where I can easily switch back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the .xpi is just a zip file so if you unzip it you can edit the files inside

You can edit install.rdf (and maybe ec2gui.rdf) to change the maxVersion to 4.0.*: See here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_an_add-on_to_change_its_compatibility While you are making changes, you can make a few more to update ElasticFox: Fix background transparency: http://dirty-code.blogspot.com/2011/03/problems-with-elastic-fox-in-ff4.html Add support for new EC2 instance types...

taken from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/elasticfox/develop

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you very much.  Since I am on FF 4.0.1, I did not have to the transparent content issue problem, so I did not have to do that second part.  For some odd reason, after I updated the rdf file and rezipped and renamed the file on my Mac, it did not work.  FF complained about a corrupted extension.  I had to end up running the zip operation via command line.